# Finding the index of an element in a list. Binary search or use the index function?

Tags: python

I am new to python and have been coding a practice program to check a password against a list of 4 million words. My original solution was like so (will print true if password contained in the list):

```
import sys
from bisect import bisect_left 

script, password, pwlist = sys.argv
password = password+"\r\n"

l=[line for line in open(pwlist)] 
l.sort() #Must be sorted for bisect_left to work                         

print (password <= l[-1]) and (l[bisect_left(l, password)] == password)
```

I then realised I could use the index method instead, like so:

```
import sys

script, password, pwlist = sys.argv
password = password+"\r\n"

l=[line for line in open(pwlist)] #Note we don't need to sort this time

#Catch the "not in list" exception
try:
    print (password <= l[-1]) and (l[l.index(password)] == password)
except ValueError:
    print "False"
```

My second version greatly reduces the execution time because the list doesn't need sorting. Have I approached this the correct way? How does the *index()* method work? Surely it's not doing a binary search if it works for an unsorted list. Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK `index` just iterates through the list in order. O(N) is likely to be faster than an O(N*log(N)) sort plus a O(log(N)) binary search. Incidentally, have you considered doing `print password in l`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, in the first example you start out by designing out an algorithm by your own i.e. **binary search**.

In the second example you just use the python built-in `list.index()` function.

The second way is faster because the cost of sorting a list: `O(N*log(N))` is **bigger** than the cost of doing a linear search of the array: `O(N)`.

Consider this: if you have to check for multiple passwords, it would be good to **sort and store** the sorted list once, and then just use binary search on the sorted list after that.

Answer (score 2):

To use **Binary search** is better when the data structure is **already sorted** because you get it in O(log N). When you sort the list you do it in O(N*log N) and it is slower than a linear search O(N)

Comment: A corollary to this is that if you expect to do *enough* searches, it is worth taking the time up front to sort the list. (Where "enough" means roughly O(lg n) searches.)

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of `list.index` method is O(N) in worst case, based on its [Cpython function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/661cdbd617b8/Objects/listobject.c#l2148) its an optimized function that returns the index of first matched item in a list. So it would be the preferable way to go, and note that the binary search is just good when you are dealing with a sorted list.

```
listindex(PyListObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    Py_ssize_t i, start=0, stop=Py_SIZE(self);
    PyObject *v;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O|O&O&:index", &v,
                                _PyEval_SliceIndex, &start,
                                _PyEval_SliceIndex, &stop))
        return NULL;
    if (start < 0) {
        start += Py_SIZE(self);
        if (start < 0)
            start = 0;
    }
    if (stop < 0) {
        stop += Py_SIZE(self);
        if (stop < 0)
            stop = 0;
    }
    for (i = start; i < stop && i < Py_SIZE(self); i++) {
        int cmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(self->ob_item[i], v, Py_EQ);
        if (cmp > 0)
            return PyLong_FromSsize_t(i);
        else if (cmp < 0)
            return NULL;
    }
    PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError, "%R is not in list", v);
    return NULL;
}
```

But in your first code you have done a lot of extra works.

First of all you don't need to use a list comprehension to get all the lines of a file while you can simply use `file.readlines()` method.And you have a sort method too which makes your firs approach much slower than second one.

P.S if you just want to check the membership as a more pythonic way you can use a `set` object to preserve your items and just use `in` operand which its order is O(1).

Comment: Slightly pedantic note: The average case is O(1).  For a set with hash collisions it could be higher, and could (worst case) be O(n) (All items have same hash value)

Comment: @theB For a `set` I didn't said search is O(1). I said for check membership !