# Recursive Binary_Search() Python

Tags: python

I tried today to make a recursive binary search to detect an occurrence of a number in an array .

At first it worked perfectly but when i started adding items in the array it starts resulting (-1) even when the item it exist in that array

```
def Binary_Search(Data , low , high , item):
    if low <= high:
        M = (low+high)//2
        if Data[M]==item:
            return M
        elif item < Data[M]:
            high = M - 1
            return Binary_Search(Data ,low, high , item)
        else:
            low = M + 1 
            return Binary_Search(Data , low , high , item)
    else:
        return None
print(Binary_Search([1,3,6,7,9,8] , 0 , len([1,3,6,7,9,8])-1 , 8))
```

#Result = -1

Comment: binary search only works with sorted arrays.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binary Search of an unsorted list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33713643/binary-search-of-an-unsorted-list)